# Using SASS for a WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm hoping to use SASS with a new WordPress theme I'm using.

So far, I haven't been able to get it to work on my localhost using Windows. I'm assuming this is because I don't have Ruby installed, which is easy enough to install.

My question is this: If a user of my theme wants to develop their site on their localhost, will they also need to install Ruby?

If so, is there any way around this? I would prefer that users just download the theme and be able to use it without any other prerequisites.

Any info would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you will need to install ruby to run sass.. No there is no way around this (if you're planning on using sass) http://sass-lang.com/install ... A better question would be, are you creating a child theme? do you plan on keeping your 'purchased theme' up to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SASS is just a preprocessor for CSS so you only need it on your system in order to process the SASS files into CSS.

One thing to note though, if you decide to minimize your CSS for the distribution of your theme, you will need to model your root SASS file with the following comments:

```
/*!
Theme Name: {Theme Name}
Theme URI: 
Author: {Your Name}
Author URI: 
Description: 
Version: 0.1
License: GPL-3.0
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html
Tags: 
*/
```

The "!" after "/* is important as this will tell SASS that this comment is important and it will retain it no matter how you want your CSS output. If you do not, SASS can strip out all comments (which you normally want) but without that comment header, WordPress will not recognize your theme as a valid one.

Comment: You're welcome. You might also look into using Compass and Autoprefixer as well. These work good for a managed workflow with Grunt/Gulp/etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install ruby on your local dev environment to build your SASS theme. Your theme available for download should just have the versioned .css files not the .scss build files, though it shouldn't hurt to include them.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it :)